# Plate Bender speed issue

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

It would seem that Gregtech's Plate Bending Machine can only take up to 3 overclocker upgrades before it ceases to function. However, the largest hump in the speed of my AE crafting system is this bending machine, and frankly, 3 overclockers is not enough.
If I connected multiple Plate Bending Machines to my network's crafting network, is the AE network smart enough to use the machines in a blanket fashion? If not, how else could I speed up the crafting of Metal Plates in my system?

Comment: [I am Bender, please insert girder.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4JBFPFDEUo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You overclock the Plate Bending Machine 3 times, the reason its processes are still slow is not because the overclocks fail to increase the speed enough. The machine is actually performing poorly due to energy flow issues. Applying two Transformer upgrades and a Laptronic Energy Upgrade in addition to the 3 Overclocker upgrades gives you a Plate Bender that bends plates just as fast as any of the machines in Advanced Machines. (Dont forget to upgrade the power line to the Bender to better support it's new energy needs.)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue as well.  My method for handling the issue was to have a [level emitter](http://ae-mod.info/ME-Level-Emitter/) turning on or off an exporter, that was set up to request more plates be created by the system if the amount was below a certain threshold (say 100).  I would rarely need more 100 at a time, so it gave the system time to automatically replenish it's buffer supply by the time I needed more.

The Exporter would be configured to create your plates, and export into a chest that has an Importer attached that then directly imports it back into your network.  I have 3 double chests setup for this exact purpose in my base.  Each one has 9 sets of exporters / level emitters.

Comment: what's an emitter

Comment: @Ender see link in edited answer:  It basically emits a redstone single when a particular item count is above or below a particular level.

Comment: I'm not accepting this yet only because I want to see what other solutions turn up

Comment: you can export directly into an interface and each interface can have 5 such exporters setup to it (leaving 1 face for the connection to the network), 4 if you want to save space. also the exporter need to be set to **craft only** (the hammer) otherwise you create an infinite loop

Comment: @ratchetfreak If I understand you correctly is the only difference the cost?  You're suggestion is 5 exporters and one interface, vs 1 double chest, 9 exporters and 1 importer?

Comment: or a bunch of hoppers going down into an interface with 4exporters on each, which means 1 interface+4exporters+n*(1 hopper + 4 exporters)

Comment: @ratchetfreak And the math continues... Only problem with hoppers is that it could get clogged and slow down the "Craft Only" process

Comment: Does anyone know if I could simply blanket plate benders? IE: Multiple benders in one network and the system uses them all optimally to share the work?

Answer (score 1):

For GregTech machines, when you apply overclocker upgrades, it doubles the speed of the machine, but also quadruples its energy comsumption, doubling its total energy usage in the end.

So, for most plates it takes 20 EU/t to operate the machine. So with overclocker upgrades, it would give 80/320/1280/5120 EU/t with 1/2/3/4 upgrades.

Craft yourself a portable scanner and check your machine's storage capacity. For the plate bending machine, it's 2000 EU. Each time a machine tries to perform an operation, it takes EU from its internal storage (or buffer).

TL:DR You need storage upgrades. a simple IC2 storage upgrade would give 10k EU, which would be enough, but with GT, you can craft better ones. Check them out.

And instead of overclocking your machine and supplying it with nuclear energy, try this (I'm not actually sure it'll work) :

Get yourself a ME Interface, with 4 machines. Place the Interface, then all the 4 machines all around it. Even put one under it, but leave 1 face for the ME cable. Put your patterns in the Interface. If I'm right, if you call enough plates per batch, it should send the items to one machine, then another, then another... If it works, you would stay energy efficient. And plate bending machines doesn't cost that much.